# How is the scoreDirector accessed when using the autowired SolverManager with Optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using the autowired SolverManager with the optaplanner-spring-boot-starter jar

```
@Autowired
    private SolverManager<BatchSolution, UUID> solverManager;
```

And would like to report on the constraints using:

```
Map<Object, Indictment> indictmentMap = guiScoreDirector.getIndictmentMap();
```

In previous versions I used:

```
ScoreDirectorFactory<Solution_> scoreDirectorFactory = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory();
guiScoreDirector = scoreDirectorFactory.buildScoreDirector();
```

And can't see how to access the scoreDirector through the solverManager in the examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're planning to expose this functionality in the `ScoreManager`:

```
@Autowired
ScoreManager<MySolution> scoreManager;
```

But that API doesn't support `getIndictmentMap(Solution_)` yet. This is an API gap.

Meanwhile, just workaround it, by autowiring the `SolverFactory` too and use `ScolverFactory.getScoreDirectorFactory()` until we deprecate that once the `ScoreManager` API replaces that functionality.