# How to implement a problemFactChange while using optaplanner-spring-boot-starter?

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner 8.3.0.Final with optaplanner-spring-boot-starter and everything works as expected except that I can't figure out how to implement a problemFactChange.

This question: [How is the scoreDirector accessed when using the autowired SolverManager with Optaplanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431478/how-is-the-scoredirector-accessed-when-using-the-autowired-solvermanager-with-op) mentions autowiring solverfactory and then using Solverfactory .getScoreDirectorFactory(). But I can't see how to use that to access the solver being used by the wired solverManager, which I believe is all I need to "addProblemFactChange", which should then change the problem fact when the solver can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API gap that `SolverManager` lacks an `addProblemFactChange()` method.

[Vote for it.](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2141)

**Workaround**

Without the high-level `SolverManager` API, the workaround is to use the low-level `Solver` API instead:

```
@Autowired
SolverFactory<MySolution> solverFactory

public void runSolver() { // don't call this directly in an HTTP servlet/rest thread
    Solver<MySolution> solver = solverFactory().buildSolver();
    solver.solve(myProblem); // hogs the current thread
}

public void doChange() {
    solver.addProblemFactChange( ... /* do change */);
}
```

Comment: Ge0ffrey, Thanks once more for your help. I think I've been asking questions for a decade now. I couldn't use Optaplanner without it. Is the Solver created with the autowired solverFactory linked to the one used by SolverManager? Or would the workaround mean using SolverFactory entirely? I'm using features from the SolverManager like the Listen, and the threading.

Comment: I voted for it. Is there also a "Pay for it" link somewhere? Then I can make that an option for the customer if the workaround isn't enough.

Comment: Red Hat (who employs all OptaPlanner full time developers, QA etc) offers support and consulting subscriptions. If a customer request comes in, for example for this feature, it's a top priority over any and all community requests like this. See https://www.optaplanner.org/product/services.html

Comment: Is this added to the api? I also need addProblemFactChange in solverManager