# OptaPlanner Spring boot application with addProblemFactChange

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

I read the question already posted here [How to implement a problemFactChange while using optaplanner-spring-boot-starter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025030/how-to-implement-a-problemfactchange-while-using-optaplanner-spring-boot-starter)

Has there been any progress on this feature request? I would also like to submit problemFactChange() events to the REST based SolverManager instance. I think this is an important gap in current SolverManager API, especially to make more engaging web application one needs solveAndListen() as well something like submitProblemFactChange() to let user trigger a fact change in ongoing optimization.

Is there a work around that uses SolverManager?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, SolverManager API does not support problem fact changes. We are aware of this major limitation of the API and we are moving towards addressing it. We do not yet have a timeline for when it will be available.

In the meantime, I believe you can have a `Solver` instance autowired, to which you can send PFCs. The only caveat is that you'd have to implement your own `solveAndListen()`, as `Solver` will block whatever thread it runs in.