# Implement problem change on solver instance created from solverManager.solveAndListen() [Optaplanner version 8.14]

Tags: optaplanner

If I'm using the 8.14 version of Optaplanner, not considering the option to move to a later version. Is there a way for me to implement problem change(real-time planning) using the solver instance created from solverManager.solveAndlisten() not the solver.solve()?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to move to a newer version? Is there some new bug, some incompatibility? We want to know, so that we can address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in 8.14 it's not possible to do problem fact changes on the `SolverManager`.

Either upgrade to 8.17 or use the workaround suggested in this answer: [How to implement a problemFactChange while using optaplanner-spring-boot-starter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025030/how-to-implement-a-problemfactchange-while-using-optaplanner-spring-boot-starter).

The workaround injects `SolverFactory`, builds a `Solver` instance and uses `solver.solve()`.